# Yocto: method not to include a bbappend file

Tags: yocto

I have a bbappend file that I need to include on some target platforms and not include on others.
I tried adding BBFILES_remove += ".../my_package_%.bbappend" to see if it doesn't include the file, but that doesn't work.

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BBMASK` is what you're looking for:

```
BBMASK += "/layer/my_packagegroup_%.bbappend"
```